Testing method annotated with @Cacheable
I have to test a method thats annotated with @Cacheable like this im not,that skilled so this may be wrong.
    @Trace
    @Cacheable(value = "pp-search")
    public Response search(final String fcId, final String group) {

        final Response searchCriteria = ppSearch.builder()
                .warehouseId(fcId)
                .groupType(group)
                .build();

        return getPpResponse(searchCriteria);
    }

The thing is that i want to test the cached behavior by hitting the search method once and then cleanning the mocks to verify that the data got indeed cached, so the cached will be hit twice.
my cached config is this:
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
@AllArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class CacheConfig {

    private static final int EXPECTED_FCS = 60;
    private static final int GROUPES = 4;

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        final SimpleCacheManager cacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();
        cacheManager.setCaches(List.of(
                concurrentMapCache("process-path-search", (EXPECTED_FCS * GROUPES),
                        2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                )
        );

        return cacheManager;
    }

    private ConcurrentMapCache concurrentMapCache(final String name,
                                                  final int size,
                                                  final int duration,
                                                  final TimeUnit timeUnit) {
        return new ConcurrentMapCache(
                name,
                CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
                        .expireAfterWrite(duration, timeUnit)
                        .maximumSize(size)
                        .build()
                        .asMap(),
                false);
    }
}


im trying to test it like this:
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureCache
public class ppClientTest {

    @Autowired
    private ppClient ppClient;

    @Autowired
    private CacheManager cacheManager;

    @Test
    public void testSearchCaching() {
        //GIVEN
        final Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put(ORDER_TYPE_PARAM, GROUP_ORDER);
        mockGetPpByCodeRequest(HttpStatus.SC_OK, expectedPpResponseFiltersTwd(), OPERATION_TYPE, HOUSE_ID, params).build();

        //WHEN
        ppResponse response1 = ppClient.search(HOUSE_ID, GROUP_ORDER);

        cacheManager.getCacheNames().forEach(System.out::println);

        Cache cache = cacheManager.getCache(""pp-search"");
        String cacheKey = HOUSE_ID + ":" + GROUP_ORDER;
        assertNotNull(cache.get(cacheKey));

        cache.clear();

        ppResponse response2 = ppClient.search(HOUSE_ID, GROUP_ORDER);

        assertEquals(response1.hashCode(), response2.hashCode());
    }
}

but im no able to test succesfully the cached method, the client call is fine and work fine, but when im trying to get the cached im getting null, so i dont know if i have to mock the cache as well
